# What ads to choose if pubcenter is not supported

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, admob, nokia, ads

I have developed a xna game. Pubcenter in my country is not supported. I have found a few solutions:

- AdRotator : combining some primary ad network with AdDuplex, but what ad network(s) to choose ? What probabilities and etc ?
- Nokia ad exchange : something new on the market, i found nothing about what ecpm could be?

So what is the best option for me ?

Of course it is interesting about how those ad networks are compared to pubcenter by ecpm, fill rates to expect what i can get .